# WinXP : after entering safemode display is fuzzy/blurry

Tags: windows-xp

I entered Safe Mode on an XP box (yeah, I know, it's OLD but it still works fine) and after it came out of it, the display is now blurry / fuzzy - across the entire display. From the icons on the desktop, to the font on Netscape, everything is now rendered in some kind of low resolution font that makes it unreadable.

I tried to get it to upgrade the display device driver, but it reported that it is 'up to date'.

This is just so strange ..  I mean, why should going into safe mode result in an unusable computer?

Has anyone ever experienced something like this?

Ok, I guess I will have to probably scrap this box.  I'm feeling down.  But, this is not the way it should come to an end.

TIA !!

DOn

Comment: I think this question might fit better over at SuperUser.com, rather than StackOverflow.com.

Comment: well, Stackoverflow has a 'winxp' tag.  I will try over at SuperUser.com though.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter in Safe Mode, low resolution video is activated, but doesn't change anything IN the hardware, your video card might be damaged, usually weird colors and crappy random images are a memory error common problem, the buffer to show the image, is corrupted.

Comment: it was fine before I entered safe mode.  Upon exit, the fundamental dynamic of display was changed such that now everything is rendered in not only a lower resolution but a very blurry lower resolution.  I see your point about a memory problem in an old box, but it would be a strange coincidence for that to start to occur at the same time I happened to enter safe mode.

Comment: What happen when you change the resolution to a higher value (Color too)?